# SQL convert data from columns into one row

Tags: sql, rows

I have a table in `SQL` that looks like:

```
name  age apples banana kiwi
mary  5   R3.00  null   null
mary  5   null   null   r6.00
mary  5   null   r9.50  null
joane 8   null   r9.60  null
joane 8   r5.00  null   null
```

I need to convert it to:

```
name    age apples  banana  kiwi
joane   8   r5.00   r9.60   (null)
mary    5   R3.00   r9.50   r6.00
```

How do I do this is `SQL`?

Comment: GROUP BY and for example MAX. What do you want to happen if Mary has two different Kiwi values?

Comment: Yes, but how do I get the fruit to lend up on the same row per person?

Comment: Mary will never have 2 different kiwi values

Comment: By the way, the blanks are nulls

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? Please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: Why do you have 3 rows for Mary, why don't you do an update not an insert and have Mary stored as one row initially?

Answer (score 0):

Try

`select sum(age), sum(apples), sum(banana), sum(kiwi) from table group by name`

Comment: thank you. what if the values within the columns are not rand values, instead it is text...how do I do it?

Comment: it is a bad idea to `sum` age ;)

Answer (score 0):

You should just group by name and take min/max of each value

```
select 
    name, max(age) age, max(apples) apples, max(banana) banana, max(kiwi) kiwi
from table group by name
```

Comment: thank you. what if the values within the columns are not rand values, instead it is text...how do I do it?

Comment: @MissR It would be ok, `MAX` aggregate function is defined for both text and number values.

Answer (score 0):

Use `DISTINCT` & `NOT NULL` in a sub query as the values are text not numbers (so `SUM` wont work).

```
SELECT DISTINCT yt.name, yt.age, 
(SELECT yta.apples FROM yourtable yta WHERE yta.name = yt.name AND yta.apples IS NOT NULL) AS apples, 
(SELECT ytb.banana FROM yourtable ytb WHERE ytb.name = yt.name AND ytb.banana IS NOT NULL) AS banana, 
(SELECT ytk.kiwi FROM yourtable ytk WHERE ytk.name = yt.name AND ytk.kiwi IS NOT NULL) AS kiwi
FROM yourtable yt
```

OUTPUT

```
name    age apples  banana  kiwi
joane   8   r5.00   r9.60   (null)
mary    5   R3.00   r9.50   r6.00
```

SQ FIDDLE: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/88bc53/11/0

N.B. Also please consider your naming convention, either all plural or not (apples & kiwi/banana).

Comment: subqueries are redundant here i think, we could do this with just aggregation

Comment: @agent5566 Possibly, it depends on what other data is populated in the fruit fields.